# npm run-script build(production build) command, shows source code in browser in React JS

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to React JS development, and I created my React application using the `npm create-react-app` command. When I finished my development and built my application code, with an `npm run script`, this created a new build folder which I then deployed with my server.

The issue here is the following: after deployment if I open my website in Chrome and run developer tools I am able to see all my source code instead of minified code within Chrome, see image below:[image].

Answer (score 3):

to avoid showing source code in browser inspector window, you have to disable the flag GENERATE_SOURCEMAP , to do so just update your package.json build script command as follows

```
scripts: {
  "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
}
```

Ref: github -> https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4162#issuecomment-373658997

Answer (score 2):

React is a library to ease the development of your User Interface for your website. It is written in JavaScript and **JavaScript runs on the client-side** by default. i.e. **within your browser**. Code which is *executed on the client-side can be viewed on your browser by default*. This is *true regardless of the client-side framework you choose* whether it be React, Backbone, etc... If you don't want others to see your code within the browser I would consider developing your UI with with a server-side templating engine. With that being said, you can obfuscate your JavaScript if this is a big concern of yours so it's harder for others to see what you're doing. Here is a link to a [JavaScript Obfuscation tool](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator) you can utilize.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: No you can see any JavaScript code: minified/unminified since it 's client-side code. It is up to you to minify the code yourself. Most people minify their JavaScript code prior to releasing to production to reduce the number of bytes needed to be downloaded by browser to run their web application. This is why when you inspect code a lot of the time it's minified code: (.min.js files)

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

you are using the devtool: 'source-map' in your webpack so please remove the devtool: 'source-map' from your file.
you can take a reference from https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/

Comment: I create my react application using cli command --- npm create-react-app, not with webpack